Why is the condition: $1\prec m$ for any monomial $m\neq 1$ needed in definition for monomial ordering?
Background
Let $k$ be a field, $A=k[x_1,\ldots x_n]$ and let $\mathfrak{M}$ denote the set of monomials in $A$.
Definition:  We will introduce an order relation $\prec$ on $\mathfrak{M}$.  We define $\prec$ to be an admissible order relation on $\mathfrak{M}$ if it is a total order which is compatible with the multiplication of monomials, i.e.,
$(1)$ For any paire of monomials $m,n$ we have $m\prec n$ or $n\prec m$ or $m=n$
$(2)$ if $m_1\prec m_2$ and $m_2\prec m_3$ then $m_1\prec m_3$
$(3)$ $1\prec m$ for any monomial $m\neq 1$
$(4)$ if $m_1\prec m_2$ then $mm_1\prec mm_2$ for any monomial $m$.
Questions
For the above Definition, I want to ask why condition
$(3)$ $1\prec m$ for any monomial $m\neq 1$,
is necessary?  I mean monoimials consists of indeterminates of the form $cx_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}, c\in k\setminus \{0\}$ where $\alpha_i\in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.  It seems to be a superfluous/redundant condition. I try to find examples that shows why $(3)$ is necessary from various books that has the topic monomial ordering or groebner bases, but have not have any success so far.
Thank you in advance.

What is $\mathfrak M?$

@ThomasAndrews I edited my post adding what $k, A, \mathfrak{M}$ mean.

You need a well-order on monomials, so that the division algorithm terminates. This is because for a well-order, every strictly decreasing sequence must terminate after only finitely many steps.
As there is a countable number of monomials, it is equivalent to having a total ordering (conditions 1 and 2) with a minimal element (condition 3).
We choose 1 to be the minimum (where 1 is the monomial where all exponents are 0), so that it respects condition 4. In effect, if we choose $m \neq 1$ as a minimum, then
$$
m \prec 1 \implies m^2 \prec m,
$$
contradicting the minimality of $m$.

having a countable set is equivalent to the set having a total order with a minimal element.  Is that a basic result from naive set theory?

If you ask if it is easy to prove, the answer is yes. The $\implies$ direction is true for any well-order, and the $\impliedby$ is true because if you take a subset $A$, which is countable, you can list the elements, and place them in order ($a_0 \prec a_1 \prec a_2 \prec \ldots$), so it as a minimum.

ah kk.  thank you for your help
